# kubectl top nodes shows error: metrics not available yet

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, heapster

I'm using Kubernetes 1.7 and running hepaster. When I run

```
kubectl top nodes --heapster-namespace=kube-system
```

it shows me

```
error: metrics not available yet
```

I also tried this

```
kubectl top nodes --heapster-namespace=kube-system --heapster-service=heapster --heapster-scheme=http --heapster-port=12213
```

Where the heapster is running then it shows following error.

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services http:heapster:12213)
```

Any clue for tackling the error?

Comment: It's working now. The heapster was not configured properly.

Comment: I have the same problem too. How did you solve it?

Comment: Is your heapster running properly? Are you able to access it via terminal command `curl -L http://heapster-pod-ip:heapster-service-port/api/v1/model/metrics/`?

Comment: When I run that command it returns this results: `{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "model \"metrics\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get model at the cluster scope",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "metrics",
    "kind": "model"
  },
  "code": 403
}`

Comment: Do you see any error in the log of heapster container?

Answer (score 3):

It means that heapster is not properly configured.

You need to make sure that heapster is running on `kube-system` namespace, and check if the `/healthz` endpoint is ok:

```
$ export HEAPSTER_POD=$(kubectl get po -l k8s-app=heapster -n kube-system -o jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}')
$ export HEAPSTER_SERVICE=$(kubectl get service/heapster --namespace=kube-system -o jsonpath="{.spec.clusterIP}")
$ curl -L "http://${HEAPSTER_SERVICE}/healthz"
ok
```

Then, you can check if the metrics API is available:

```
$ curl -L "http://${HEAPSTER_SERVICE}/api/v1/model/metrics/"
[
  "cpu/usage_rate",
  "memory/usage",
  "cpu/request",
  "cpu/limit",
  "memory/request",
  "memory/limit"
 ]
```

If it's not returning as above, take a look at container logs for errors:

`$ kubectl logs -n kube-system ${HEAPSTER_POD} --all-containers`

---

Although, keep in mind that Heapster is a deprecated project and you may have problems when running it in recent Kubernetes versions.

See [Heapster Deprecation Timeline](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster/blob/master/docs/deprecation.md):

> ```
> | Kubernetes Release  | Action              | Policy/Support                                                                   |
> |---------------------|---------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
> | Kubernetes 1.11     | Initial Deprecation | No new features or sinks are added.  Bugfixes may be made.                       |
> | Kubernetes 1.12     | Setup Removal       | The optional to install Heapster via the Kubernetes setup script is removed.     |
> | Kubernetes 1.13     | Removal             | No new bugfixes will be made.  Move to kubernetes-retired organization.          |
> ```

Since Kubernetes v1.10, the `kubectl top` relies on **metrics-server** by default.

[CHANGELOG-1.10.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG-1.10.md#other-notable-changes-20):

> - Support metrics API in `kubectl top` commands. ([#56206](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/56206), @brancz)
>
> This PR implements support for the `kubectl top` commands to use the
>   metrics-server as an aggregated API, instead of requesting the metrics
>   from heapster directly. If the `metrics.k8s.io` API is not served by the
>   apiserver, then this still falls back to the previous behavior.

It's better to use a `kubectl` version `v1.10` or above, as it fetches the metrics from metrics-server.

However, beware of [`kubectl` Version Skew Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/version-skew-policy/#kubectl):

> `kubectl` is supported within one minor version (older or newer) of
>   `kube-apiserver`

Check your `kube-apiserver` version before choosing your `kubectl` version.